# Android AChartengine : filling plot with a different color

Tags: android, achartengine

Am writing a simple Android App where am drawing a line chat using AChartEngine. Am trying to fill the plot circle (i.e. inside the circle) with orange color. this is different from the plot line & circle color, which is purple in this case.

If I set

```
     xySeriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
```

then it is filling the circle also with purple. But I want the inside color to be orange for teh plot circles. Any help?

Now, I have set setFillPoints(false) ans you can see the sample graph in the below link

https://docs.zoho.com/viewembeddoc.do?docId=o319tf3df85f1e9224f3e83210d356e364359&ftype=image&filename=Screen%20Shot%202013-10-22%20at%203.15.07%20PM.png&imgWidth=770&imgHeight=515

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
xySeriesRenderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_graph));
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Why do you think this will solve the issue? As it stands, this answer is not very useful.

Comment: you can set above by taking other series to be plot with same range(X,Y) or say with same point with scattered or Bubble Chart.